# Displaying Static Images at 100% in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, css, image, openlayers-3

I would like to display static images as maps using a StaticImage layer in ol3, at 100% of the image size in pixels.  I believe this should be defined by the extent and zoom variables, but the displayed images are not always the correct size, depending on the image, so I am clearly misunderstanding something, in spite of all of the forum entries I have read.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Animik/3hr5gpw8/) demonstrating incorrect image sizes.  The reference image is 128x128 pix, but the displayed image is slightly larger at zoom 0.

The [provided example from OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/static-image.html) works just fine if used in my fiddle, and we seem to learn that if the extent variable is [0,0,wid,len], then zoom: 2 is 100%.  But this does not hold with all images.

How can static images be reliably displayed at 100% of their size in pixels?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var extent = [0,0,128,128]  // image size is 128x128 px
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'local_image',
    units: 'pixels',
    extent: extent
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
        zoom: 0,
    }),
    controls: [],
});

var im_layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'http://img4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071014061100/freeciv/images/1/1c/Crystal_128_penguin.png',  // image size is 128x128 px
        projection: projection,
        imageExtent: extent
    })
})
map.addLayer(im_layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this problem.  Instead of using the "zoom" variable in the map view, use the "resolution" parameters instead.

Setting the following, in addition to the above, results in an image displayed at 100%:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    view: new ol.View({
        resolution: 1,        // important for 100% image size!
        maxResolution: 2,     // must be >= 1
        //minResolution: .5,  // also set-able
        //zoom: 0,            // don't use this
        ...
    })
    ...
})
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hr5gpw8/3/).